# How do I find resource leaks in Win32?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005, memory-leaks

After running some hours my application fails in creating a new font object:

> CreateFontIndirect() returns NULL.

I know how to find memory leaks (i.e. using parallel inspector or another profiler - most of them include leak detection). But how can I locate a resource leak in Win32?

Comment: First confirm you have a GDI handle leak - look at the GDI Handles column in Task Manager.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grab yourself a copy of [GDI View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) - this useful tool can show all the GDI objects used by your app, including details on the font name, size, etc.  This has proved very handy in the past.

For Win32 apps you might want to look at the WTL framework - this wraps GDI objects with lightweight C++ classes that will handle object deletion for you.

Comment: Yes, this seems a very good tool. Amazingly tiny. A zip of only 50kB. Thanks.

Comment: you also can use deleaker. It's power tool!

Comment: Can it be used for Ubuntu 18.04 ?

Comment: How about non-gdi resources like files, handles, etc?

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) is handy for that.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the MSDN article <s>[Resource Leaks: Detecting, Locating, and Repairing Your Leaky GDI Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301756.aspx)</s>([via archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20141228090817/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301756.aspx)) might provide you with an answer.

Comment: Well the article is good. But the tool mentioned is not linked - i cant find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [BoundsChecker](http://microfocus.com/products/DevPartner/BoundsCheckerSuite.asp), it tracks resource leaks in addition to memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - i have BoundsChecker and it once was the best tool ever. The quality though continuously decreased since our first license (about 15 Years ago), most specifically, since compuware acquired BoundsChecker. It just terminates immediately after start and recently it stopped my whole x64 System. Compuware DevPartner (the successor of BoundsChecker) is by the way still unable to analyze 64-Bit software.